# How to get X and Y rotation from two 3D direction vector (Zero Z rotation)

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

I have two 3D direction (normalized) vector A and B. I am looking for the Euler angles to rotate A into B. I know it has many solution because it is possible to rotate a normal vector anywhere with just using two axis like X and Y or roll and pitch. I have to find the solution where the Z rotation is Zero.

I would like to create a function like this:

```
Vector3 dir1 (0, 1, 0);
Vector3 someRotation(Pi / 4, Pi / 4, 0);
Vector3 dir2 = dir1.rotateXYZ(someRotation);

Vector3 xyRotation = dir1.eulerToDirection(dir2);

// now I expect that the eulerToDirection fv calculated the X, Y rotation from the vectors at Z = 0
// so xyRotation.x == Pi / 4 && xyRotation.y == Pi / 4 && xyRotation.z == 0 is true
// aside from the floating point error
```

Of corse the `some rotation` not always 0 at the Z. It is just for the example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.You have not included syntactically valid code. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

First use `atan2(z2-z1, y2-y1)` to find the angle to rotate around the X-axis that aligns the y's and the z's. Then, use `acos`of the dot product between the just rotated vector and the final vector. This will be the angle needed for the rotation around Y. Depending on how you implemented the rotations, you might need to flip some signs.

Comment: Your answer really helped me to understand that I am wrong. Even one rotation axis fixed in zero I have infinite number of solution. In your solution we treat one axis as preferred and the other selected to get a solution. Anyway, thank you for the answer!